# How to modify the outlook Contact Card?

Tags: vba, outlook

Recent versions of Outlook have an easily accessible [Contact Card](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-contact-card-aee867d7-fb39-4101-a386-e93008c8c6a1) that gives quick information about a user. I'd like to modify this card via VBA to add a new button with custom functionality to the four button row (see image below).

My problem is that I've had a bear of a time figuring out how to programmatically access this card. It doesn't seem to be a view, as I've pulled the XML for all contact views I can find and none seem to correspond to this view (see code below image). I've read the [BusinessCardView object manpage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/businesscardview-object-outlook) and there's nothing there either indicating that this is in fact the correct object or talking about how to modify this thing. The [CardView page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/cardview-object-outlook) was equally not helpful; I can't even tell what view that object corresponds to in the Outlook UI.

Any help would be most appreciated.

---

Trying to modify the box below:

[image]

Code used to pull view XML:

```
Sub FindViews()
    Dim objView As View
    msg = ""
    For Each objView In Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Views
        msg = msg & objView.Name
        msg = msg & objView.Class
        msg = msg & objView.XML
    Next

    Dim oMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Set oMsg = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    oMsg.Body = msg
    oMsg.Display
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the same question asked on [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-msoffice_custom-mso_2013_release/how-to-modify-the-outlook-contact-card/3960b60d-3695-4537-b5fc-0fffcd97165e?messageId=6a3f93bc-3630-4905-a47b-eeb04f81b7c2):

> That card is not editable, at least not using VBA. It's not a view -
>   it pulls data from contacts or gal and AFAIK the card is not exposed
>   in the object model.
>
> You used to be able to control some of the display using a registry
>   entry but i don't know if it still works.  See
>   https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/outlook-2010/turn-contact-cards/ for the keys.